# How to get total number of lines in a file in linux using java

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to run `wc -l filename` command using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` and get the total number of lines. But it is not working.

Here is my code :

```
private String executeCommand(String command) {
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Process p;
    try {
        System.out.println(command);
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line.split("\\s+")[0] + "\n");
        }

        int exc = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println(exc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();
}
```

`exc` (the exit value) is coming out zero. When I am printing the command which I am passing, it gives the right command. I have also tried to copy that command and run it in Linux. It's working, but not through program.

Command which I am passing to command variable in the functionexecuteCommand is:
    wc -l < log1

Total number of lines it contains around 4597110. Also I dont want the size of file in bytes, I have to get the total number of lines only.

Comment: Show the actual command, please. Also the output you are getting and how many lines there are in the file in reality.

Comment: wc -l will give total line number so no need to read again

Comment: @Prashant it depends how many files you give it as parameters.

Comment: @RealSkeptic : got your point but if he is checking only one file then there is no need to read the file..

Comment: I can't see any problems with your code. looks like the problem is somewhere else. Just one suggestion, you should close the BufferedReader after your while loop (reader.close())

Answer (score 4):

An easier alternative for getting the lines (with Java 8).

`long lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("foo.txt")).count();`

Comment: Nobody like a smart alec :-) However, we _do_ like those knowledgable in the language, especially the newer features which, admittedly for Java, I haven't kept up with. Good show. Presumably you'd need to be circumspect with large files if they're loaded into memory all at once, yes? Not that it degrades your answer, just something we may need to be aware of.

Comment: No, never mind, it looks like `lines` gives you a stream object so it's probably not held in memory all at once.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with all Java 8 intricacies myself, but they've met a lot of great progress even with older classes. The Java 7 version of `Files` offers very little useful functionality, especially for boilerplate like reading all bytes or lines.

Answer (score 3):

Kayaman has a much better answer if you're on Java 8 or better. If, however, you're stuck on an earlier iteration, see below.

---

You see *this* bit of code that you use for evaluating the output of `wc`:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
    output.append(line.split("\\s+")[0] + "\n");
}
```

That's *remarkably* similar to the code that could just read the file directly and count the number of lines.

So I'm not entirely certain why you think there's a need to call an external program to do this task, *especially* as it degrades the portabilty of your code.

Just open the file and read the lines, adding one to a counter for each line. And there you have it, the line count.

See, for example, the following file:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
public class Test
{
    static private int getLineCount(String fspec) {
        String line;
        int count = 0;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(new File(fspec)));
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null)
                count++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            count = -1;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println (getLineCount("/tmp/tempfile"));
    }
}
```

Running this gives `140` as does the output from `wc -l`:

```
pax> wc -l /tmp/tempfile 
140 /tmp/tempfile
```

Comment: that is what  i also thought!! wc -l will give result then why that circus :D

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't pass correct path to the file, try this when you run method:

```
URL fileName = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("filename");

System.out.println(executeCommand("wc -l " + fileName.getPath()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Process` in the following way:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("wc", "-l");

try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));){ 
    Process process = pb.start();                
    while (reader.readLine() != null){
        // you need to figure out in which line the 
        // relevant output is and parse that to int
        // just look at some sample outputs of wc -l
    }
    int err = process.waitFor();
    if(err!=0) {
        // your code for processing the number of lines goes here
        // the command finished without error
    }
    else {
        // your code here in case the command had an error
    }
 } catch (Exception e){
    // catch an Exception like IOException or InterruptedException here
 }
```

Basically the `Reader` will read the output from the command that would go to the terminal when executing the command there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache common io [FileUtils.readLines(File file)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines(java.io.File))

```
FileUtils.readLines(new File("filename.txt")).size()
```